# How to create a streaming server side connection using libcurl?

Tags: curl, streaming, libcurl

I want to create a streaming connection from client to server. The client will once connect to server and keep listening for responses from the server. Stream teardown can happen when client requests.

Example:

1. Connect to server
2. Keep listening for responses to server. Something like `while(streamOK){
    //execute function when response arrives}`
3. Teardown connection when `CloseStream()` invoked.

I have gone through libcurl but couldn't find a clear implementation of streaming connection except rtsp one.

Comment: There's no difference between "streaming" or non-streaming in libcurl. Just ask for the resource and receive the data in a callback.

Comment: @DanielStenberg can it be done like a async push from server? where client keeps listening and whenever server gets some trigger it will send response to client? 
If yes can you please point out the API?